# Can I reach a device if I know its local IP address and the ip address of the router its connected to?

Tags: ip, remote-access, router, lan

On my home network there is printer I want to print from. I know the the local IP of my printer at home, and I know the IP address of my home router.

From a different location, is there any way I can access the printer with these pieces of information?

Comment: You need to configure port forwarding (or a VPN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From inside the network (while you're connected to your router at home) that would be enough information. However from outside the network, the firewall on the router would have to be set up. The place you would want to set up would be the Port Forwarding feature of your router.

While at home:

1) Login to your router

2) Look for something like "Port Forwarding/Port Triggering", "WAN", "Firewall" or something like that. It will be different on different routers.

3) Most of the time the default port for network printers is 9100 so you can set up traffic coming into the router on port 9100 to be forwarded to the printer's IP address. This is why it's called "Port Forwarding" because you're forwarding traffic on that port.

4) Once that's set up you'll have to set up a printer on your computer and use the public IP address of your home router. For example, it will be something other than "192.168.x.x".

There you have it!

Comment: Also make sure that the printer has secure authentication, or anyone in the internet will have access to it.